# ngx-bootstrap / Angular 6 ..... can show one component and change title component

Tags: angular

I have three component with the same design but different in title and used ngx-bootstrap to show , i can use one component instead of component? I can sent parameter with `.show()` to  change title,

```
openAbsenceDaysReportPopup() { 
    this.modalRef = this.modalservice.show(StudentsAbsentDaysReportComponent, {
        animated: true,
        keyboard: false,
        backdrop: true,
        ignoreBackdropClick: true,
        class: 'sar'
    });
}
```

Comment: can you please share code on stackblitz

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please, revise it and make some edits. Also, if you can, please share your code on stackblitz.